# Intellisense on Visual Studio 2015 RC for bower.json file is not working properly.

Tags: asp.net, bower, visual-studio-2015

When I tried to add the dependencies in bower.json file. Intellisense does work for name but it does not work for version. For version it only shows "*" (Any available version of the package).

After I added just "*". its not able to get the appropriate or any version of the dependencies...

e.g I tried to add one for bootstrap.

```
"dependencies": {
          "bootstrap": "*"
  }
```

bower bootstrap#~3.3.4      not-cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.3.4
bower bootstrap#~3.3.4         resolve git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.3.4

I have to install through command line to make it work like "bower install bootstrap --save". Is there any way that I can just type in bower.json file and show the available version of bootstrap. Or am I missing any extra plugins for that in VS 2015 RC.

Comment: im using the community edition and i get no Intellisense seems broken :(

Comment: Mine has the same issue

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be a valid issue since `Beta7`.

Corresponding Github Issue can be found and tracked here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/219

Answer (score 0):

I installed ASP.Net 5 RC1 this morning and get the version intellisence work now :D. But it doesn't give any help to suggest the list of packages matching the input characters.

I still believe that this issue happens because of the proxy